# MCU: Agents of SHIELD/Age of Ultron viewing order?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, suggested-order, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield

So, as has been known for a while (and which should surprise absolutely no one), [Agents of SHIELD and Age of Ultron will impact each other's stories](http://screenrant.com/avengers-2-age-ultron-agents-shield-connections-episodes/). Can someone please name, **without any spoilers,** where Age of Ultron should fall for the best cross-MCU story?

(Clarification – Here's what I mean by best: My mom watched all of AoS S1 before watching Winter Soldier. Clearly a bad move, as Winter Soldier was obviously meant to be the big reveal for what then shakes up the remainder of AoS. When, relative to the recent/upcoming AoS S2 episodes, should Age of Ultron be watched to make sure all the big reveals happen at the proper time?)

Comment: @JasonBaker Fair enough. That post doesn't mention Age of Ultron yet, but it took me to the [MCU wiki timeline](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), which does. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question refers to the first _Avengers_ film, this refers to _Age of Ultron_.